# Clique no LoginButton do facebook no android usando Xamarin com FaceBookSDK não acontece nada

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, facebook-sdk, xamarin.android

Estou usando Xamarin para tentar logar com o facebook, já gerei o Hash e o appID. ( Aparentemente está correto, pois anteriormente o app me retornava uma msg dizendo que o HASH era inválido ). Segue o código da minha activity:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.ActivateApp(this);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Register events logs of the facebook
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        AppEventsLogger.DeactivateApp(this);
    }
    public override View OnCreateView(View parent, string name, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(this.ApplicationContext);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splash);



        var callbackmanage = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
        LoginButton loginbutton = (LoginButton) base.FindViewById(Resource.Id.login_button);
        var fcb = new facebookCallBack();

        loginbutton.RegisterCallback(callbackmanage,fcb);


    }

    private class facebookCallBack : IFacebookCallback
    {
        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get
            {
                return new IntPtr();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void OnCancel()
        {

        }

        public void OnError(FacebookException p0)
        {

        }

        public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object p0)
        {

        }
    }
```

Acontece que agora quando clico no botão de login, nada acontece. Ele não dá nenhuma mensagem de erro, nem entra nos métodos de callback ( `OnError`, `OnPause` etc), não dá absolutamente nada.

Desse modo, fico perdido.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Você não colocou nada nos métodos que `implementam IFacebookCallback`  como vai capturar o retorno? Veja este exemplo: https://gist.github.com/rmenezes/d1a98e18f19c6555c6c2

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Mas eu havia colocado no debug, breakpoint em todos métodos que implementei da IFacebookCallback. Nenhum deles pausou. 
Vou verificar o exemplo!

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa de pelo menos uma linha de código dentro do método para o breakpoint entrar. Coloque uma linha de log e coloque o breakpoint na linha de log.

```
private class facebookCallBack : IFacebookCallback
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return new IntPtr();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teste Dispose");
    }

    public void OnCancel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teste OnCancel");
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException p0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teste OnError");
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Teste OnSuccess");
    }
}
```

> Tente...

Substitua o **AppEventsLogger.ActivateApp(this);** por **AppEventsLogger.ActivateApp(getApplication());** e coloque essa linha no **void OnCreate**.

Mova o **AppEventsLogger.DeactivateApp(this);** para o **void OnDestroy**.

Se funcionar de um feedback.